# I am having issues with this.props.navigation.navigate in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

I have been trying to create a touchable highlight that takes to me a new scene by using this.props.navigation.navigate for a react-native app. However, react native gives me an error that says undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation'). Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
View,
ListView,
Image,
Text,
ScrollView,
TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import beerlist from '../datbeerlist.json';
import BeerDetails from './BeerDetails';

const squadIcon = require('../../img/serioussquad.jpg');

class BeerList extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
   rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
 });

 this.state = {
 dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(beerlist),
 };

 }


 renderRow(beer) {

return (
  <View style={styles.row}>
    <Image style = {styles.icon} source  = {squadIcon}/>
    <View style={styles.info}>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('BeerDetails')}>
      <Text style={styles.items}>
      {beer.name} 
      </Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.total}>
      <Text style={styles.price}>${(beer.price / 100).toFixed(2)}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
}
```

Any ideas on how to get it fixed?

Comment: Are you using Redux? And how do you navigate to this component?

Comment: I'm using stack navigator with react-navigation

Comment: how did you configure the navigator? BeerList component should be within a navigator component (stack/drawer) navigator. It would be nice to also include that part of your code here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Although @justelouise is right and the

> StackNavigator Definiton

part of the code would help, still, if you've navigated to this page using stack navigator then it's been added to the stick navigator already.

I think `this.props.navigation` is available under the `render()` method. If you want to use it in another method, then you have to pass it from `render()` to the method you want. Something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ListView,
  Image,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import beerlist from '../datbeerlist.json';
import BeerDetails from './BeerDetails';

const squadIcon = require('../../img/serioussquad.jpg');

class BeerList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(beerlist),
    };
  }


  renderRow (beer, renderNavigation) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Image style={styles.icon} source={squadIcon}/>
        <View style={styles.info}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => renderNavigation.navigate('BeerDetails')}>
            <Text style={styles.items}>
              {beer.name} 
            </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.total}>
          <Text style={styles.price}>${(beer.price / 100).toFixed(2)}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );

  render () {
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderRow(BEER, navigation)}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are navigating to `stackNavigator` outside of `render()` then try this

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation })=>{
        const { navigate } = navigation
        return{
            title: 'Header Text',
            headerRight:(<Button 
            title="Settings" backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)" color="rgba(0,122,255,1)"
            onPress={() =>navigate('settings')}
        />)
        } 
    }
```